# HP-UX and RHEL ping difference

Tags: porting, ping, rhel, hp-ux

I have these two commands for different environments..

> ```
> for HP-UX: "ping someaddress 10" 
> for RHEL: "ping someaddress -c 10"
> ```

Im Porting an application from HP-UX to RHEL and i cant tell if these two commands have same results since, I dont have a HP-UX system.

I have read the HP-UX manual
( http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01922497/c01922497.pdf )
but still it doesn't help since no options were specified in the command.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to a HP-UX shell via the [HP Alliance](http://www.hp.com/go/pvp) program. Registration is required. This might help you to test your scripts.